# Slow running MySql restore - 10 times slower than backup speed and still going

Tags: mysql, database, restore, database-restore

I'm moving a large (~80GB) database from its testbed into what will be its production environment. We're working on Windows servers. This is the first time we've worked with MySQL and we're still learning the expected behaviours.

We backed up the data with

```
mysqldump -u root -p --opt [database name] > [database name].sql
```

Which took about 3 hours and created a file 45GB in size. It copied over to its new home overnight and, next morning, I used MySQL Workbench to launch a restore. According to its log, it ran

> mysql.exe --defaults-file="[a path]\tmpc8tz9l.cnf"  --protocol=tcp --host=127.0.0.1 --user=[me] --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments --database=[database name]  < "H:\[database name].sql"

And it's working - if I connect to the instance I can see the database and some its tables.

The trouble is, it seems to be taking forever. I presumed it would restore in the same 3-4 time frame it took to back up, maybe faster because it's restoring onto a more powerful server with SSD drives.

But it's now about 36 hours since the restore started and the DB is apparently 30GB in size. And it appears to be getting slower as it goes on.

I don't want to interrupt it now that it's started working so I guess I just have to wait. But for future reference: is this treacle-slow restore speed normal? Is there anything we can do it improve matters next time we need to restore a big DB?

Comment: Were you able to increase your restore speed performance?  It would be nice to see some before/after numbers. We finally decided to test the integrity of our backup (a 550GB DB) by restoring it in another environment and OMG it is so slow!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Very large imports are notoriously hard to make fast. It sounds like your import is slowing down--processing fewer rows per second--as it progresses. That probably means MySQL is checking each new row to see whether it has key-conflicts with the rows already inserted.

A few things you can do:

Before starting, disable key checking.

```
   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
   SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0;
```

After ending restore your key checking.

```
  SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 1;
  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

And, if you can wrap every few thousand lines of `INSERT` operations in

```
   START TRANSACTION;
   INSERT ...
   INSERT ...
   ...
   COMMIT;
```

you'll save a lot of disk churning.

Notice that this only matters for tables with many thousands of rows or more.

`mysqldump` can be made to create a dump with that disables keys.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_disable-keys

```
mysqldump --disable-keys
```

Similarly,

```
mysqldump --extended-insert --no-autocommit
```

will make the dumped sql file contain a variant of my suggestion about using transactions.

In your case if you had used `--opts --no-autocommit` you probably would have gotten an optimal dump file. You already used `--opts`.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my.ini and got some improvements while also using `mysqldump --extended-insert --no-autocommit`

my.ini for 16GB RAM on Windows 10 mysql 7.4

```
# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir="C:/xampp74/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir="C:/xampp74/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "C:/xampp74/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
#innodb_buffer_pool_size=16M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8G
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
#innodb_log_file_size=5M
innodb_log_file_size=2G
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M

#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
#Use for restore only
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2

innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50
```